# Помогите разобраться с рекурсивной функцией

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Имеется рекурсивная функция: http://jsbin.com/hojedoraka/1/edit?js,output

Мне не совсем понятно как она работает.

В функцию попадает 3 - значение counter. Затем counter уменьшается, становится 2. На следующем шаге выводится синий параграф со значением 2. Дальше условие, если counter не равен 0 - функция рекурсивно вызывает себя. При следующем запуске значение counter уменьшается и становится 1. Далее единица выводится в синем параграфе. Затем снова срабатывает условие, т.к. counter еще не равен 0, функция снова вызывает себя, уменьшая counter до 0 и выводя 0 в синем параграфе. На следующем шаге counter попадает в условие, на котором рекурсивные вызовы заканчиваются. Функция выводит 0 в желтом параграфе. А вот дальше мне непонятно, почему выводятся 1 и 2 в желтом параграфе?

Почему дальше выводятся 1 и 2 - это из-за предыдущих вызовов, которые затем начали возобновляться. Но вот почему они выводятся именно в желтом параграфе?

**Обновление**

Я прекрасно понимаю, почему выводятся числа 2, 1, 0 в синем параграфе, — потому что срабатывает условие if(counter != 0) и функция вызывает сама себя. При counter == 0 условие не срабатывает и f(0) завершает вызов, выводя 0 в желтом параграфе. Но почему затем интерпритатор, завершая предыдущие вызовы - 1 и 2 выводит их в желтом параграфе, а не в синем, мне вот это непонятно.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Я попытался нарисовать](https://www.dropbox.com/s/clcnpmnnse8zy8t/IMG_20141112_173803.jpg?dl=0), если так непонятно, то я хз, как объяснить.

```
function f(counter) {
    counter--;
    document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter + "</p>");

    if(counter != 0) {
        f(counter) // когда интерпретатор доходит сюда, управление передается функции f ( 2 ), потом так же само управление передается f( 1 ).
    }// Продолжит он уже к примеру тут и пойдет дальше

    // На f( 0 ) интерпретатор наконце то доходит сюда,НО продолжает он уже после вызова функции f(x) т.е он доходит до конца каждой функции. поэтому сначала 0, потом
   // он поднимается на уровень вышел где counter == 1, поэтому еще выше где counter == 2.

    document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter + "</p>" );
}

f(3);
```

Comment: Это все понятно, мне не понятно, почему он выводит в желтом параграфе?

Comment: Может, просто потому что функция доходит до желкотого после отрисовки синего? Так как она по сути зацикливается в том промежутке. Если бы вам было понятно, то вы бы не спрашивали.

Comment: @Decode функция не дойдет до желтого, пока не закончит вызывать саму себя.

Comment: @Decode добавил ссылку на рисунок в ответ.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю почему выводятся числа 2, 1, 0 в синем параграфе — потому что срабатывает условие if(counter != 0) и функция вызывает сама себя. При counter == 0 условие не срабатывает и f(0) завершает вызов - выводя 0 в желтом параграфе. Но почему затем интерпритатор завершая предыдущие вызовы - 1 и 2 выводит их в желтом параграфе, а не в синем, мне вот это не понятно. [Картинка](http://savepic.su/4444359.png)

Comment: Все, офф. На Stack Overflow уже объяснили.

@cyber_ua, спасибо за ваши разъяснения, они мне тоже помогли.